# facebook share with jquery and reset cache everytime when share for new

Tags: jquery, facebook-share

How I can place new image and title and description for every time 
Here's code that I'm using

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&autoLogAppEvents=1&version=v3.2&appId=1794722553977426';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

i want to change image and title and description on click and share 
like there are 4 list and every list contain different title , image and description

Comment: What is broken in your current code? You only seem to import some external js.

Comment: So, when you hit "share" button again, it just share the old image/text/description instead of the new one?